# Override Hysterix Logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, hystrix

I am trying to understand the logs generated by SpringBoot before and after implementing Hysterix Circuit Breaker

Before Hystrix the logs looked like,

```
17:31:35.977 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [TransID:bcc8a9e9-41b7-47c8-9eb1-0f8becb42f68] INFO  c.f.e.common.logging.MethodLogging - Entered Class: class com.org.myapp.service.MyService, Method: getData, Arguments: 123456
```

After implementing Hystrix the logs looks like,

```
17:21:23.197 [hystrix-MyController-1] [TransID:] INFO  c.f.e.common.logging.MethodLogging - Entered Class: class com.org.myapp.service.MyService, Method: getData, Arguments: 123456
```

So, how did `http-nio-8080-exec-2` get replaced with `hystrix-OrchestratorController-1`, and why it's not showing my `TransactionId` when Hystrix got implemented. How did Hystrix take over the logging? What's the difference between both? Is there any way to revert back to my old logging format?
I tried `hystrix.command.default.requestLog.enabled=false` in my application.properties, but no luck.

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
class MyApp{
}
```

RestController

```
@GetMapping("...")
@HystrixCommand(commandKey="data")
public Object getData(){
}
```

application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

Comment: Hystrix uses a threadpool to do timeouts hence the different threads. Not sure what should provide the transid in your logs, but that might is probably stored in some thread local and retrieved, instead use the MDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hystrix is using its own thread instead of the local thread. That's the reason your log looks different.

Add this property in your application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=SEMAPHORE
```

Now hystrix will use your local thread.